# Cannot import name 'read_data'

Tags: python

I've been trying to follow the following code from [github](https://github.com/sajeed786/Earthquake-Prediction/blob/master/Feature_1_time.py)

Though, when I run this code:

```
from filter import read_data, path_list,threshold
```

I first thought It was the issue of not installing `filter` so, I installed filter `pip install filter`, though I get this error:

> cannot import name 'read_data' from 'filter' (c:\users\emil\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\filter_*init*_.py)

Could it be that it's not sourced from filter, and its the authors file? I would greatly appreciate your comments.

Comment: How are you running the code, i.e. what command are you executing in what directory? `filter` appears to be a module from the same repo, so you can `pip uninstall filter` because you probably don't need it.

Comment: Okay, so in this case "filter" is reference filter.py which is 1 directory above the file you're working on. This is _not_ in reference to the pypi:filter module found here: [pip install filter](https://pypi.org/project/filter/)

Comment: @Xinthral I assumed it was something along those lines. Although, how would I install that directly from the command-line? given that it too follows `pip install filter`?

Comment: You're calling code you haven't written/copied yet.  It's not a pip module to be installed, it's a local module; So it's calling [filter.py](https://github.com/sajeed786/Earthquake-Prediction/blob/master/filter.py) for these functions, `read_data, path_list, threshold`. If you open that file you can see the functions.  The easiest way to explain is import filter is going to look through the standard library and site-packages for a filter module, and if it doesn't find it there it will look in the local directory for a <packagename>.py {in this case filter.py}.